# PostgreSQL: Performance penalty for joining two tables in separate schemas

Tags: postgresql

Is there a performance penalty when joining two tables in separate schemas (However in the same database).

My physical model has several distinct sections that fit nicely into their own schemas, however I occasionally need to join across schemas and I've been unable to find any information on if this has a negative performance impact.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, a schema is just a namespace.

Performance might be different when tables (or their indexes) are stored on different tablespaces. One tablespace might be on a fast storage device, the other on a slow one. But that's your choice and has nothing to do with a schema.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a link to any official documentation on this?

Comment: Check the system table [pg_namespace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-namespace.html) and [pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-class.html) where all inforamation about tables is stored. pg_class is also the table where the queryplanner gets it's information to select the best queryplan. Use EXPLAIN to get the queryplan.