# Grouping postgresql tables in schemas

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I'm currently building an app that contains around 60 or so tables, some with meta information, some with actual data and a couple of views on top of them.

To keep things organized I'm prefixing all table name with **meta_** or **view_** respectively, but might it be worth it to just put them in different schemas inside the same database?

1. It this common practice?
2. Any reasons to not do this?
3. Can I create FK-constraints over different schemas?

---

PS: There seems to be no performance penalty judging from this answer: [PostgreSQL: Performance penalty for joining two tables in separate schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619480/postgresql-performance-penalty-for-joining-two-tables-in-separate-schemas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use schemas in any way you like. No limitation in principal. They are especially useful if you need to [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html) certain rights to groups of objects, for instance to separate users inside a database. You can largely treat them like directories in a file system (the analogy has its limits, though).

I use `v_` prefix for views and `f_` prefix for functions. But that is basically just notational convenience to spot those objects quickly in a text search - if I hack the dump for instance. Make such prefixes **short**, you will have to type them for the rest of your database life. Multiple prefixes from various semantic layers could have to apply to a single object.

I would **not** mix functional prefixes (`v_` or `view_`) with semantic prefixes (`meta_`) on the same level. Rather create a separate schema for meta-objects and use prefixes to denote object types throughout all your schemata.

Whichever system you chose, stay consistent! Or it will do more harm than good.

Comment: I assume "no limitations" means that FK's will just work as expected since schema's are merely namespaces in postgresql?

Comment: @ChrisR: You assume right, foreign keys across multiple schemas are not a problem. They work just like inside the same schema.